# How can I pre populate a textfield with one value based on a pk in django

Tags: django, django-forms, populate

Having a model of Preorder and Product I created an inline formset.
A client can make a preorder(FK).

My goal for this inline formset is to have **only** a pre populated value in a textfield and not all the values.

My desired prepoppulated value is related with the pk of the client.

Here is my view:

```
class PreorderProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Preorder
    fields=['preorder_date','client']
    template_name='test/test.html'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super(PreorderProductCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data['client']=Client.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')) #
    print(Client.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')))#

    if self.request.POST:
        data['formset'] = PreorderProductFormSet(self.request.POST)#bound the formset with data

    else:
        data['formset'] = PreorderProductFormSet()#empty formset

    return data

def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    formset = context['formset']
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
    return super(PreorderProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)



def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    return reverse('client_list')
```

I can fetch the pk of the current client successfully but I can not feed the returned client object to my data dictionary and finally can not load only the desired client object.

Here is my url:

```
url(r'^preorders/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.PreorderProductCreateView.as_view(), name='preorder_edit'),
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So in your models.py, PreorderProduct has a many to many fields pointing to Client table ?

Comment: class Preorder(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,verbose_name=u'Πελάτης')
    preorder_date = models.DateField("Ημ/νία Προπαραγγελίας",null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    preorder_has_products=models.ManyToManyField(Product,blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('preorder_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

Comment: @May.D this is the preorder model